# VCS checkout mode - agent side: build stopped on updating sources

Tags: git, version-control, teamcity

some problems with Teamcity (Enterprise 9.1.6 (build 37459). I want to make commits from the build, and for this reason I need to choose VCS checkout mode: Automatically on agent (if supported by VCS roots). But after that my build hang out on step: Updating sources. Maybe it looped, cause I see in logs, that after `git.exe -c core.askpass=C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\pass9094605598664979347.bat fetch --progress origin branch:branch` build starts another `git init`. What does it mean and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. We use Windows 10 on agent, and there is a locking folders where system processes are running. To avoid this, you need to create folder on C:\ and use it as a custom path in VCS rules.